# Desenhar linhas em representação gráfica de árvore binária

Tags: java, swing, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária, awt

Estou tentando desenhar uma árvore binária usando swing e awt em java. Já consigo mostrar os nós da árvore mas não estou conseguindo desenhar as linhas de um nó pai a seus filhos.
Tenho as classes Node, TreeGUI, DrawTree e Main. Esta imagem é como está a saída sem as linhas.

[image: Árvore binária]

Minha intenção é mostrar linhas de um nó pai a seus nós filhos. Tentei usar o método `drawLine` da classe `Graphics` mas ficou assim:

[image: Arvore]

O método drawTree define a posição dos valores dos nós na tela e guarda em ArrayLists a posição dos nós. O método drawLine desenha as linhas.  Acredito que as linhas estejam dessa forma porque os valores são guardados nessa ordem específica. Já tentei de diversas maneiras e não consigo ligar as linhas de forma correta. De que maneira posso mostrar as linhas apenas de um pai a seus filhos?

```
public class TreeGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public Node node;
    public DrawTree drawer;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TreeGUI(Node node) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        drawer = new DrawTree(node);
        contentPane.add(drawer);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        this.node = node;
        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class DrawTree extends JPanel{

    public Node node;
    public static ArrayList listX = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList listY = new ArrayList();


    public DrawTree(Node node){
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        DrawTree(g, 0, getWidth(), 0, getHeight() / node.getheight(node), node);
        listX.clear();
        listY.clear();
    }

    public void DrawTree(Graphics g, int StartWidth, int EndWidth, int StartHeight, int Level, Node node) {
        String data = String.valueOf(node.getValue());
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int dataWidth = fm.stringWidth(data);

        g.drawString(data, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2, StartHeight + Level / 2);
        listX.add((StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2);
        listY.add(StartHeight + Level / 2);
        drawLine(g, node);

        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            DrawTree(g, StartWidth, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getLeft());
        }
        if (node.getRight() != null)
            DrawTree(g, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, EndWidth, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getRight());
    }

public void drawLine(Graphics g,  Node node){
       for (int i=1; i < listY.size(); i++)
            g.drawLine((int)listX.get(i-1), (int)listY.get(i-1), (int)listX.get(i), (int)listY.get(i));
    }
```

}

método main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node raiz = null;
    raiz = raiz.insert(raiz, 35);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 25);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 75);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 30);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 20);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 12);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 6);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 23);
    raiz.insert(raiz, 90);
    TreeGUI gui = new TreeGUI(raiz);
}
```

Comment: como você quer que fique o desenho final? Os filhos desse Node só são o getLeft() e o getRight()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta com essas modificações que fiz, provavelmente vai funcionar, testei com uma classe Tree que já tinha implementada e deu certo, espero ter ajudado.

```
public void DrawTree(Graphics g, int StartWidth, int EndWidth, int StartHeight, int Level, Node node) {
    String data = String.valueOf(node.getValue());
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int dataWidth = fm.stringWidth(data);

    g.drawString(data, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2, StartHeight + Level / 2);
    listX.add((StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2 - dataWidth / 2);
    listY.add(StartHeight + Level / 2);
    drawLine(g, node);

    //Imprime as linhas que ligam os nós a seus filhos
    if(listX.size() > 1){
        g.drawLine((int)listX.get(listX.size()-2), (int)listY.get(listY.size()-2), (int)listX.get(listX.size()-1), (int)listY.get(listY.size()-1));
    }

    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        DrawTree(g, StartWidth, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getLeft());
    }

    if (node.getRight() != null){

         /*Como a recursão visita os nós da esquerda primeiro, se o nó que está sendo tratado for o filho à direira e
            houver filho(s) à esquerda, quer dizer que os filhos à esquerda já foram visitados e suas linhas já foram 
            desenhadas, ou seja, seus pontos devem ser removidos, para evitar que sejam desenhados outra vez. 
         */
        if (listX.size() > 1 && node.getLeft() != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < node.getLeft().getHeight(); i++){
                listX.remove(listX.size()-1);
                listY.remove(listY.size()-1);
            }
        }
        DrawTree(g, (StartWidth + EndWidth) / 2, EndWidth, StartHeight + Level, Level, node.getRight());
    }
}
```